# css - table-cell div goes outside of screen in Firefox and IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox, cross-browser

I have a responsive layout made of divs with `display: table` style. Layout consist of multiple div-table and inside one of those there is a div with `overflow-y: scroll` which goes outside of the screen when there is too much of a content and it's open with Firefox or IE (Works perfect on Chrome).

Try to open in Chrome and Firefox or IE to see the difference.
https://jsfiddle.net/nikolay_baychenko/wqsq5vjm/12/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution by using different methods of layout. Seems like the layout I used with `display: table` style is incorrect in a first place. table-cell simply expands considering it's content and browser takes responsibility how it is going to behave. So using table-cell layout seems not possible in current case.

Here are same layouts but done with different methods:

https://jsfiddle.net/rpx53bLt/

https://jsfiddle.net/wokgof25/ (With IE 8 and 9 support)